# GENEXUS: método GetOldValue() y función Old() no funcionan

Tags: genexus

En GeneXus 17 U2 no tienen efecto la funcion Old() y el metodo atributo.GetOldValue()en una TRN. Existe alguna alternativa para obtener el valor anterior?

Ambiente C# net

Comment: Agustín, ¿podrías aclarar un poco más el problema? ¿No funciona nunca o es un caso particular? ¿Qué es lo que tienes programado? ¿Qué otras cosas intentaste?

Comment: Buenas Marcos gracias por responder!, Es una TRN que no tiene parametros de entrada y tiene la rule equal(att,valor), los old() y algun accept de algun campo de web form

Comment: Te animas a editar la pregunta y agregar alguna captura de como lo tenes programado en las rules? Gracias!